# Tried to register two views with same name RNCWebview

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview, react-native-instagram-login

I need to integrate social media login like LinkedIn and Instagram.
For LinkedIn i have used:- react-native-linkedin .
For instagram i have used :- react-native-instagram-login.

both npm uses webview of a different version which is causing the issue as mentioned below
"Tried to register two views with same name RNCWebview"
so is there any way to centralize version of webview or any other way to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. I ended up using react-native-webview and passport in backend and removed those third party libraries.